# Maximum Profit- Memoization,DP,optimality

Tags: algorithm

I was practicing the problem on Algorithm games , I tried the following problem but couldn't find the efficient way to do it::

So can you please help me.Here is the problem.

This is the exact link::
http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm228

Comment: I am not able to solve it efficiently,Although i read many tutorials on Game theory /Strategical game, also refred this one http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=algorithmGames but stil not able to generate the idea ..

Comment: @mshsayem It is somewhat irrelevant to this problem: unless you know a specific technique, your attempt will almost certainly be so far off the mark that it does not provide a valid starting point for further discussion.

Comment: @mshsayem:: I am not able to start properly,tried brute force but it becomes very slow for N>=100.So any how to approach,start this problem .Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you would like to solve this one by yourself, so I will give you a hint: this problem has [optimal substructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure).

Imagine that you have both solutions for `N-1` coins (without the leftmost one and without the rightmost one). Would it be easy to calculate a solution for `N` coins then?

You can use two related techniques to exploit this property - [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and its subtype called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The idea is to store a solution to each sub-problem with `L` coins missing from the left and `R` coins missing from the right (use an `NxN` array for it). Before solving a sub-problem, check the array to see if you've already solved it. You would need to solve at most `N^2/2` subproblems to arrive at a solution.

Here is pseudocode for a memoized solution:

```
// solved[L][R] array contains the highest value a player could get
// on a subproblem where L coins are missing from the left
// and R are missing from the right of the original sequence on his move
int solved[N][N] // initialize each element to -1.
int coins[N]     // initialize with coin values 

int solve(int L, int R) {
    if (L+R == N) return 0; // No coins remain
    if (solved[L][R] >= 0) return solved[L][R];
    int remaining = sum(coins from L to R)
    int takeLeft = remaining - solve(L+1, R);
    int takeRight = remaining - solve(L, R+1);
    int result = max(takeLeft, takeRight);
    solved[L][R] = result;
    return result;
}

main() {
    int alice = solve(0, 0);
    int bob = sum(coins) - alice;
}
```

I remember TopCoder running this problem some time in early 2005 or 2006, but I do not remember enough details to search their problem archive.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight.Can you please provide Pseudo Code.Its bit tough to understand for me,as i m not very good at Dynamic Programming .Thanks!

Comment: @Jack I fixed a bug in my pseudocode, the previous one was not right.

Comment: Had a problem in understanding a couple of things,what is sum(coins from L to R) and what is coins.Length(is coins.length=N)?

Comment: `coins.Length` is indeed `N`. `sum(coins from L to R)` is the sum of coins remaining in the game, i.e. with `L` coins missing from the left and `R` coins missing from the right of the sequence. I also fixed an off-by-one issue in the pseudocode, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using [dynamic programming](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Dynamic_Programming).
State can be represented by:

```
set of available coins,
whos turn it is
```

For each state you should compute maximal amount of money that person in turn can win.

Hint: Rules of this game allow to describe `set of available coins` as interval.

@edit

```
for(int interval_size = 1; interval_size <= n; interval_size++) {
    for(int interval_start = 0; interval_start + interval_size <= n; interval_start++) {
         // result[interval_start][interval_start + interval_size] depends only on
         // -> result[interval_start][interval_start + interval_size - 1]
         // -> result[interval_start + 1][interval_start + interval_size]
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible number of set of available coins are 2^n so this can't be a good solution. except you prove this is NP-Complete or harder problem.

Comment: You don't really care about whose turn it is in the DP state.

Comment: I'm agree with lVlad, there is two possibilities: you check the turns, you don't check them, If you check, possible intervals are dependent to each other and will be 2^n * n^2 if you don't check the turn your algorithm is wrong, you can explore your hint.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - you can solve it in O(n^2) with no turn checking. See my answer.

Comment: @lVlad, Yes I know, I said this to Jaroslaw make clear his way. Also Jaroslaw: your answer is wrong right now, you can test it.

Answer (score 2):

Let `dp[i, j] = maximum profit alice can make for the coints i, ... j`.

We have:

```
dp[i, i] = input[i] for all 1 <= i <= N
dp[i, i + 1] = max(input[i], input[i + 1])
dp[i, j] = max(// take first coin, opponent will minimize your next move
               input[i] + min(dp[i + 2, j], dp[i + 1, j - 1]),
               // take last coin, opponent will still minimize your next move
               input[j] + min(dp[i, j - 2], dp[i - 1, j - 1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@ IVlad ::Implement your code ,its giving incorrect answer.Had I implemented it properly??
int coins[1000];
int dp[1000][1000];
int main()
 {
int T,N;//N=How many coins are there
cin>>T; //No of Test Cases.
while(T--)
{
    cin>>N;
    for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
    {
        cin>>coins[i];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
    {
        dp[i][i]=coins[i];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
    {
        if(i+1<=N)
        dp[i][i + 1] = max(coins[i], coins[i + 1]);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=N;++j)
        {
            if((i+2)<=N && (i+1)<=N && (j-2)>=1 && (i-1)>=1 && (j-1)>=1)
            dp[i][j]=max( (coins[i] + min(dp[i + 2] [j], dp[i + 1][ j - 1])),coins[j] + min(dp[i] [j - 2], dp[i - 1] [j - 1]));
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[1][N]<<endl;//Answer
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: @IVlad::Sorry neglect above post,I was wrongly implementing ur pseudocode.Ur solution got accepted thnz